# Replace src attribute in string with 'script' tag using JS

Tags: javascript

There is some string with "script" tag, for example:

I need to get RegExp to replace content of src attribute with 'newSrc' variable. This regexp must allow using double and and ordinary quotes in src attribute. I think about

```
/src="(?:[^'\/]*\/)*([^']+)"/g
```

But I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try. Tested on some websites and seems to work correctly.
However it assumes there will be no whitespace characters (it shouldn't contain it, as it's not allowed - whitespaces need to be encoded) in the src attribute.

```
var regex = /src=['"]([^\s]+)['"]/; // there is a capturing group so that you can view just the stuff in src.
```